# How Do You Read Input As Redirection From Program In Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read input from a file in bash, but want to discard the first line of a file because of the header rows in the CSV. The `tail -n+2 "${csv}"` works by itself but when using the `<` I am getting error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `-n+2'
```

The code I'm trying to make work is:

```
while IFS=, read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20 c21 c22 c23 c24
do
    description[$i]="${c3}"
    current_ip[$i]="${c10}"
    new_ip[$i]="${c12}"
    new_netmask[$i]="${c13}"
    new_gateway[$i]="${c14}"
    i=$i+1
done < tail -n+2 "${csv}"
```

Can someone please help provide a working form of `< tail -n+2 "${csv}"` and explain the solution?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `read -a` to stuff everything into one array rather than a bunch of individually-named variables?

Comment: I wanted to split them into different arrays for ease of use in additional code not shown in this question.

Comment: There's probably an easier way to write that additional code than to need to deal with a bunch of individually-named variables per column. That said, some of those easier ways would require bash 4.3, so I can't give a conclusive answer without details.

Answer (score 4):

The easy answer here is to use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
while ... done < <(tail -n+2 "$csv")
```

This works because `<(tail)` is replaced, by the shell, with a filename which connects to the output of `tail`, either via a named pipe or, on platforms that support it, a `/dev/fd` alias.

Thus, when run, this will become something like (pseudocode):

```
tail -n+2 "$csv" >/dev/fd/63 &
while ... done < /dev/fd/63
```

...or (and this latter is what you might do if trying to write this code for POSIX sh, or otherwise a shell without comparable functionality):

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d csvpipe.d.XXXXXX)
mkfifo "$tempdir/csvpipe.tmp"
tail -n+2 "$csv" >"$tempdir/csvpipe.tmp" &
while ... done <"$tempdir/csvpipe.tmp"
rm -rf "$tempdir"
```

...though your shell won't need the overhead of a temporary directory to use in creating its FIFO, this is somewhat safer than using `mktemp -u`, and far safer than a fixed/hardcoded temporary file name.

Comment: @EtanReisner, err, this is process substitution, not command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `tail`, just read directly from the file, but use a compound command (`{...}` and two `read`s to discard the first two lines.

```
{ read; read;
  while IFS=, read ...; do
      ...
  done
} < "$csv"
```